# Reading docvars from filenames with Quanteda

Tags: r, text, quanteda

The documentation for quanteda says that this is the way to import text files from a folder and to read metadata from the filenames:

```
require(readtext)
mytf5 <- readtext("directory/*.txt",docvarsfrom="filenames", sep="-", docvarnames=c("Year", "President"))
```

I have these files in the directory:

```
[1] "1866-marx.txt"     "1910-weber.txt"    "1958-williams.txt"
[4] "1982-bell.txt"     "1998-lindgren.txt"
```

When using the code above, I get:

```
Error in file(f, ...) : unused argument (sep = "-")
```

This is in spite of me having "-" separators in the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're technically using the **readtext** package, not **quanteda**, and while we are about to submit **readtext** to CRAN, it's still only on GitHub.  I'm not sure which version you are using, but you have the syntax wrong.  Here is the correct call:

```
> packageVersion("readtext")
[1] ‘0.3’

?readtext::readtext

readtext(file, ignore_missing_files = FALSE, textfield = NULL,
  docvarsfrom = c("metadata", "filenames", "filepaths"), dvsep = "_",
  docvarnames = NULL, encoding = NULL,
  verbosity = getOption("readtext_verbosity"), ...)
```

So: the command you need is:

```
require(readtext)
mytf5 <- readtext("directory/*.txt", docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep="-",
                  docvarnames = c("Year", "President"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using the most recent GitHub version of `readtext` installed through `devtools::install_github("kbenoit/readtext")`. Love your tutorials, but obviously your code has changed somewhat since you made them. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks! Vignette on **readtext** coming within a week and then we will submit it to CRAN.